# Simulate from kernel density estimator with variable underlying grid

Tags: r, random, probability-density, kernel-density

I have a dataset that I'm using to create an empirical probability distribution by estimating a kernel density. Right now I'm using R's [`kde2d`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/kde2d.html) from the MASS package. After estimating the probability distribution, I use [`sample`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html) to sample from slices of the 2D distribution along the x-axis. I use `sample` much like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39706438). Example code would look like this

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(123)
x = rnorm(100, 1, 0.1)
set.seed(456)
y = rnorm(100, 1, 0.5)
den <- kde2d(x, y, n = 50, lims = c(-2, 2, -2, 2))
#to plot this 2d kde:
#library(lattice)
#persp(den)
conditional_probabilty_density = list(x = den$y, y = den$z[40, ])
#to plot the slice:
#plot(conditional_probabilty_density)
simulated_sample = sample(conditional_probabilty_density$x, size = 10, replace = TRUE, prob = conditional_probabilty_density$y)
```

The `den` looks like this

[image: kde2d]

My data has *known* areas where there is a lot of fluctuations, requiring a fine grid granularity. Other areas have basically no data points and nothing is going on there. I would be fine if I could just set the `n` parameter of `kde2d` to a very high number in order to have a good resolution of my data everywhere. Alas, this is not possible due to memory constraints.

That's why I thought I could modify the `kde2d` function to have a non-constant granularity.
[Here](https://rdrr.io/cran/MASS/src/R/kde2d.R) is the source code of the kde2d function. 
One can modify the line

```
gy <- seq.int(lims[3L], lims[4L], length.out = n[2L])
```

and put whatever granularity is wished for on the y-axis. For example

```
a <- seq(-1, 0, 0.5)
gy <- c(a, seq.int(0.1, 2, length.out = n[2L]-length(a)))
```

And the modified `kde2d` returns the kernel density estimate at the specified positions. Works very well. Suppose I have now

[image: kde2d_2]

*Problem is*, I can no longer use `sample` to sample from slices along the x-axis. Because the part on the left side of the distribution is much finer and thus has a higher probability to be sampled by `sample`.

What can I do to have a fine grid where I need it, but sample from the distribution according to its proper densities? Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `approx` on `conditional_probabilty_density` with a new `n`.