# Create Bi-variate probability density to sample from in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, simulation, montecarlo

I have some data that has two variables: spend and outcomes and they are given at a weekly frequency.
I would like to model the relationship between the two at a yearly level, but do not have enough years worth of data to build a model. I do have about 3 years worth of weekly data, however, and would like to simulate several more weeks of data points (spend and outcomes) based on a bi-variate probability density between spend and outcomes which I could then use to roll up to a yearly frequency.

Is there a package in R that can take take two variables and find an estimate for the density function which I could then use to simulate many more data points?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `simulate_kde` function in the package [simukde](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simukde/simukde.pdf) will internally make a kernel density estimation and create samples from it.

Alternatively, the `MASS` package has the `kde2d` function to obtain a bivariate kernel density.

You could then sample from that, as for instance described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399038/simulate-from-kernel-density-estimator-with-variable-underlying-grid).